# How to get back gerrit Abandoned commit?

Tags: gerrit

I have some changes in my gerrit Abandoned commit is there any way to merge it again?[image: This image shows the Abandoned commit]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just:

1. Click on the change ("rebased to resolve merge conflict" text)
2. Click on the "Restore" button to reopen the change

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done from your bash:

```
$ ssh -p <port> <host> gerrit review --restore <change-id>
```

For more information see https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-review.html